# Gulp: Enable Inline Javascript in Less

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-less

i am using front end build process with gulp. As a part of my less compiler, i am getting this error " Inline JavaScript is not enabled. Is it set in your options?". Found this solution for Webpack. I am trying to find a solution for gulp config. 
[Enable inline javascript in LESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46729091/enable-inline-javascript-in-less)

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. I think i found the answer.
gulp.task('less', function () {
  return gulp.src([
//src files
      ], { cwd: "/path/.."})
   .pipe(less(**{javascriptEnabled: true}**))
//function to handle error
   .on('error', handleError)
   .pipe(target/..);
});

Answer (score 3):

Thanks. I think i found the answer.

```js
gulp.task('less', function () {
  return gulp.src([src/..], { cwd: "/path/.."})
   .pipe(less({javascriptEnabled: true}))
   .on('error', gutil.log(gutil.colors.red('[Error]'), error.toString());)
   .pipe(target/..);
});
```

});