# Antd uses deprecated javascriptEnabled

Tags: javascript, webpack, less, antd, less-loader

[Antd](https://ant.design/) says [here](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme) that inline javascript should be enabled in less with the `javascriptEnabled: true` option. However, this option has been deprecated for Less as of version 3.0.0 due to security concerns as it is vulnerable to code injection, which is mentioned [here](http://lesscss.org/usage/) (search for "Enable Inline JavaScript (Deprecated)") and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58343406/how-to-replace-the-deprecated-javascriptenabled-option-in-less-loader-with-a-new).

Trying to fix this problem with Ant seems impractical as we will likely need to create a new plugin for every new inline javascript function used in less, and it is unclear how many instances there are and how complex that is.

Googling reveals little discussion surrounding this topic. Is there any horizon for Ant to resolve this issue or possible work arounds? How are other developers dealing with this issue, or are they just ignoring it? Thanks.